# why"still" put in the end of the sentence? What's the meaning?

Tags: sentence-construction

I read a sentence in FT (https://www.ft.com/content/de93525a-ee66-11e9-ad1e-4367d8281195). And I have a question:  why"still" put in the end of the sentence? What's the meaning?

The sentence as follow:

Joint research by the Brookings Institution and Financial Times is bleaker ***still***, describing our situation as “synchronised stagnation”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to ELL Stack Exchange.

The use of the word "still" as an adverb after a comparative adjective (like bleaker in the sentence presented) in end position is not unusual.  You can do so to give force to/emphasize the comparative adjective.

However, the use of "even"  is more idiomatic and common than that of "still" for emphasizing a comparative adjective.

So the phrase "even bleaker" is more common than "bleaker still"/"still bleaker".

Comment: "It goes dark... it goes darker still" _A Night Like This_ The Cure (1985)